# JavaFX conflicting with Poi-Ooxml maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx, apache-poi

I have the following Maven project setup in Eclipse Neon (4.6.1)
Running Java 1.8.0_121, and using Java FX.

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.jcgay.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-color</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I have a very basic GUI, that I run with this code :

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/GUI.fxml"));

rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
}
```

This works fine.

But as soon as I add this dependency in Maven :

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

The program fails to start.
I get no error in the console, it just says Terminated in Eclipse.

I was able to reproduce with different Java 1.8 versions, and was able to pin point the conflicting dependency Poi-Ooxml after many trial and error.
I have tried also different Poi-Ooxml version, but same issue.

Why is there a conflict between JavaFX and Poi-Ooxml ? How do I solve it ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :
Here is the fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane fx:id="p_main" prefHeight="489.0" prefWidth="793.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="projectname.Controler">
   <center>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1095.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="t_url" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="106.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="402.0" promptText="" text="" />
            <TextField fx:id="t_user" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="147.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="272.0" promptText="UserName" text="" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="t_pwd" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="187.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="272.0" promptText="Password" text="" />
            <TextField fx:id="t_file" disable="true" editable="false" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="232.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="404.0" promptText="File saved to ..." />
            <Button fx:id="b_export" layoutX="387.0" layoutY="147.0" onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction" prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Export" />

         </children>
      </Pane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Please provide the content of `GUI.fxml` and the controller code.

Comment: Sorry not reproducible for me. It runs without error using a simple controller `projectname.Controler` which creates a model from a `*.xlsx` file using `apache poi`. Btw.: Your `Application` would be independent of the kind of `Layout` using

`Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/GUI.fxml")); 
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();` in `start`.

Comment: Not reproducible for me either. I've tried in Idea 2015.